# Visual C++ Converting Char To std::string

Tags: c++, char, stdstring

I'm trying to get environment username and download a file to C:\username.txt
Here is my code:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
        DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
        GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
        std::string pref;

        path = "C:\"+username+".txt";

        HRESULT hr1 = URLDownloadToFile ( NULL, _T("http:// example.com/test.txt"), _T(path), 0, NULL );
        return 0;
}
```

But I don't know how to convert username to string. Also I get error when I use a string name in path. But I don't have a problem when I use "" And write the path manually. Thanks

Comment: Where is the variable declaration for `path`? Also it should be `"C:\\"` because \ has a special meaning in string litterals.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding `_T`. Just stick to wide strings for Windows API calls. Making winapi calls with the ANSI versions is quite pointless anyway.

Comment: where is `path` variables?